# How to lookup a column with a list of tuples in another column of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking for the best way to look up for the first element in the marks column in Name column and append the respective Score in the respective tuple. Here is the dataframe and the expected output

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['Nik', 'Kate', 'Evan', 'Naik'],
    'Age': [33, 34, 43, 44],
    'Score': [90, 95, 93, 92],
    'marks': [
        [('Nik', 100), ('Naik', 85)],
        [('Kate', 100)],
        [('Evan', 100)],
        [('Nik', 77), ('Naik', 100)],
    ]
})
```

Expected output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### update

Use a loop and mutate the lists:

```
scores = df.set_index('Name')['Score']

for l in df['marks']:
    for i, t in enumerate(l):
        l[i] = t+(scores.get(t[0]),)
```

Output:

```
   Name  Age  Score                             marks
0   Nik   33     90  [(Nik, 100, 90), (Naik, 85, 92)]
1  Kate   34     95                 [(Kate, 100, 95)]
2  Evan   43     93                 [(Evan, 100, 93)]
3  Naik   44     92  [(Nik, 77, 90), (Naik, 100, 92)]
```

###### previous answer

I would use a list comprehension with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and a generator with [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next):

```
df['first'] = [next((x for x in m if x[0]==n), None)
               for n, m in zip(df['Name'], df['marks'])]
```

Output:

```
   Name  Age  Score                     marks        first
0   Nik   33     90  [(Nik, 100), (Naik, 85)]   (Nik, 100)
1  Kate   34     95             [(Kate, 100)]  (Kate, 100)
2  Evan   43     93             [(Evan, 100)]  (Evan, 100)
3  Naik   44     92  [(Nik, 77), (Naik, 100)]  (Naik, 100)
```

If you want the number:

```
df['first'] = [next((x[1] for x in m if x[0]==n), None)
               for n, m in zip(df['Name'], df['marks'])]
```

Output:

```
   Name  Age  Score                     marks  first
0   Nik   33     90  [(Nik, 100), (Naik, 85)]    100
1  Kate   34     95             [(Kate, 100)]    100
2  Evan   43     93             [(Evan, 100)]    100
3  Naik   44     92  [(Nik, 77), (Naik, 100)]    100
```

Or using pure pandas (likely less efficient):

```
df['first'] = (df
   .explode('marks')
   .loc[lambda d: d['marks'].str[0].eq(d['Name'])]
   ['marks'].str[1]
   .groupby(level=0).first()
)
```

Comment: the details are a bit unclear and it looks like your input is missing the 3rd value, if this is the one you want you have to adapt my above solution to get`2` in `x[2]` or `['marks'].str[2]` in place of `1`

Comment: Please have a look at the expected output. I want the respective Score value to be appended in the tuple by joining the name

Comment: OK, that wasn't clear. See update